# Реализация Клиент-сервера

Tags: windows, tcp-ip, .net, c#

Нужно реализовать клиент-сервер. )
Есть клиент, возможно сделаю из него сервис.
И сервер. который будет посылать всего один сигнал.
В общем, задача: надо периодически обновлять некоторые файлы на клиентских машинах в офисе. Делать руками можно, но долго и... )
Сделал программку, которая в один клик сама всё делает.
Хочу сидя за своим компом. в 1 клик обновлять всем в офисе эти самые файлы.)
Как лучше сделать:

1. клиенты слушают порт моего компа. и если от него была дана команда - обновить.
2. клиенты ждут сигнала у себя. а сервер будет на каждый комп. отдельно сигнал посылать.

Больше думаю подходит первый вариант, но решил спросить совет.

И если можно, какую - то подсказку, совет, пример. а то я с сетевым программированием на  Вы пока что. )

Answer (score 3):

```
xcopy "\\имя компьютера источника\общий ресурс\" "\\имя целевого компьютера\общий ресурс\"
```

Можно завернуть в For и читать имена компьютеров из файла.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, давай пойдем по жестокому пути.
Клиентская тачка должна в себе держать запущенным какое-либо приложение, которое при команде сервера должно начать обновление. Сервер всего-лишь случает подключения и дает команду (посылает какой-нить битик ... либо битище... ).
 Если бит прилетел нужный, но клиент обновляеццо.
 Так вот.. суть в чем.
 Делаешь самое обычное получатовское приложение, например, на C#.(там все просто, разобраться можно быстро и легко)
 Серверное приложение должно вести статистику подключений (для чего: представим, что N-ое кол-во компов во время посыла бита нужного были выключены.. для того, чтобы обновить те компы, которые вовремя не получили запрос - они должны все же его принять  => мы регистрируем обновленцев, вычитаем обновленцев из общей массы компов и оставляем массив не обновившихся)
 В случае, когда необновленные компутеры коннектяццо к серверу, сервер понимает, что пора этим эстонцам дать команду т.к. они ее ранее не получали. Клиентское приложение начинает обновление. 
Кстати, лучше всего поылать нетолько битик, который говорит "Обновись!", но и версию того, что он обновляет. Чтобы можно было и клиентскому приложению решить стоит ли обновляццо и знать что послать в ответ серверу (обновлен, версия одна и та же или еще чо-нибуд)
    => Я думаю, идея моя понятна.
Зачем все так сложно ? ... Контроль - это хорошо. Меньше лишних вопросов от руководсва )))
На своей ж..пе прочувстсвовал.